# Can I use Pandas DateOffset with the number of offset days specified in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas DataFrame, with a column of dates.  I'd like to generate a new column that takes the original date, and offsets that by a number of days which is specified in another column.

I've been able to get this to work:

```
import pandas
...
df['End Date'] = df['Start Date'] + pandas.DateOffset(days=1)
```

But instead of **days=1**, I'd like to insert **df['Number of Days']**

However, I get TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.

**df['Number of Days']** is type int64, so I believe it should work.  What am I doing wrong here?  Or does **days** have to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert **Number of Days** to timedelta, and then just add.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Date': ['2020-01-01','2020-01-10']
                  ,'Number of Days': [5,10]})

df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['Number of Days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Number of Days'], unit= 'D')
df['End Date'] = df['Start Date'] + df['Number of Days']

df.head()
#output
    dates       days    end Dates
0   2020-01-01  5 days  2020-01-06
1   2020-01-10  10 days 2020-01-20
```

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work using: df['End Date'] = df['Start Date'] + df['Number of Days'].astype('timedelta64[D]')

Comment: Very nice @Daniel! that's the same logic as my answer, but a little different :-)

Comment: @Daniel to close the topic you can answer your own question and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as an answer, or accept mine :)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer.  I will try your version as well.